# how to write a file to desktop using streamwriter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, streamwriter

I have a block which is supposed to send the overwritten file to my desktop but the code does not seem to be working, I am using a MVC application not a console apllication.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong or advise me on how to achieve my solution.

```
using (var File = new StreamWriter(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "~/ColTexOutputFileTest.csv", false)) // true for appending the file and false to overwrite the file
{
    foreach (var item in outputFile)
    {
        File.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: "but the code does not seem to be working" - what do you mean by that? Do you get any exception? If so, post some details here.

Comment: If this is an MVC application, whose desktop are you expecting this to be written to? The end user, or the server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the '~' char.

```
"\ColTexOutputFileTest.csv"
```

Answer (score 1):

This character ' ~ ' used to find Server Side folder or file

**For Example** if you access App_Data folder in abc.xml file

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/abc.xml");
```

if you streamed file on local access to file as windows path

```
using (var File = new StreamWriter(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\ColTexOutputFileTest.csv", false)) // true for appending the file and false to overwrite the file
{
    foreach (var item in outputFile)
    {
        File.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

> "~/ColTexOutputFileTest.csv" **change it** "\ColTexOutputFileTest.csv"

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the answers above, the ~ is the problem. .Net provides the Path class which has a combine method for joining path & file names & not needing to know whether separators are needed :

```
using (var File = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "ColTexOutputFileTest.csv"), false))
```

See : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path(v=vs.110).aspx